# Update message in Kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am using Python Kafka topic.

Is there any provision producer that can update a message in a queue in Kafka and append it to the top of queue again?

According to spec of Kafka, it doesn't seems feasible.

Answer (score 22):

Kafka is a distributed **immutable** commit log. That said, there is no possibility to update a message in a topic. Once it is there all you can do is consume it, update and produce to another (or this) topic again